# Using an ifelse or if loop in the panel function in Lattice doesn't work with panel.xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to draw a plot with `lattice` in which both the point colours and shape change based on variables in the data. This works fine when I set the `col` and `pch` values on their own, and don't put `panel.xyplot` in the `ifelse` statement:

```
#Setup
library(cluster)
library(lattice)

xyplot(V8 ~ V7,
       data = flower,
       V8_var = flower$V8,
       panel = function(x, y, ..., V8_var, subscripts) {
         
         col <- ifelse(V8_var[subscripts] < 50,
                       'blue',
                       'orange')
         
         pch <- ifelse(V8_var[subscripts] < 50,
                       2,
                       6)
         
           panel.xyplot(x,y,type='p',
                        col = col,
                        pch = pch)
         
       })
```

[image: The 'correct' image drawn with two different colours and two different shapes]

However this does not work when I use `panel.xyplot` in an `ifelse` or `if` loop:

```
xyplot(V8 ~ V7,
       data = flower,
       V8_var = flower$V8,
       panel = function(x, y, ..., V8_var, subscripts) {
         
         col <- ifelse(V8_var[subscripts] < 50,
                       'blue',
                       'orange')
         ifelse(
           V8_var[subscripts] < 50,
           panel.xyplot(x,y,type='p',
                        col = col,
                        pch = 2),
           panel.xyplot(x,y,type='p',
                        col = col,
                        pch = 6)
         )
         
       })
```

[image: Graph with two colours of points but only one pch even though the panel function had an ifelse statement which called panel.xyplot with a different pch value depending on the value of the variable V8. Also gives the error message: "Error using packet 1 replacement has length zero".]

```
xyplot(V8 ~ V7,
       data = flower,
       V8_var = flower$V8,
       panel = function(x, y, ..., V8_var, subscripts) {
         
         col <- ifelse(V8_var[subscripts] < 50,
                       'blue',
                       'orange')
         
         if(V8_var[subscripts] < 50){
           panel.xyplot(x,y,type='p',
                        col = col,
                        pch = 2)
           } else {
           panel.xyplot(x,y,type='p',
                        col = col,
                        pch = 6)
           }
       })
```

[image: Graph with two colours of points but only one pch even though the panel function had an if loop which called panel.xyplot with a different pch value depending on the value of the variable V8.]

Using the `if` statement also gives the warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (V8_var[subscripts] < 50) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The way around this is to get the variable values through an `if` or `ifelse` statement and then plug those into `panel.xyplot` outside of any `if` statements, but I do not understand why the `ifelse` statement doesn't work as I expect when `panel.xyplot` is within it?

SessionInfo:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-41 cluster_2.1.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2    grid_4.0.2
```

Comment: Hi G. Grothendieck, The data should come with the `cluster` package, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

panel.xyplot cannot be an argument of ifelse.  Calculate pch in the same way that the code calculated col:

```
library(cluster)
library(lattice)
xyplot(V8 ~ V7,
       data = flower,
       V8_var = flower$V8,
       panel = function(x, y, ..., V8_var, subscripts) {
         
         col <- ifelse(V8_var[subscripts] < 50, 'blue', 'orange')
         pch <- ifelse(V8_var[subscripts] < 50, 2, 6)
         panel.xyplot(x,y,type='p',
                        col = col,
                        pch = pch)
         
       })
```

although in this case you don't even need a panel function:

```
xyplot(V8 ~ V7,
       data = flower,
       col = ifelse(flower$V8 < 50, "blue", "orange"),
       pch = ifelse(flower$V8 < 50, 2, 6))
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a particular reason why panel.xyplot can't be an ifelse argument?

Comment: It has to be a vector the same length as the condition vector of else length 1  and furthermore it will be evaluated even if it is in the leg that is not chosen.